# Переписать jquery на js

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

```js
$(document).on('click', '.navigation input', function() {
  var block_id = $(this).data('block-id');
  alert("gello");
  $('#' + block_id).css({
    'visibility': 'visible'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n1"><input type="button" value="2010" data-block-id="chart_div"></li>
  <li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" data-block-id="chart_div1"></li>
  <li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" data-block-id="chart_div2"></li>
  <li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" data-block-id="chart_div3"></li>
  <li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" data-block-id="chart_div4"></li>
</ul>

<div id="charts">
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2010</div>
  <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2011</div>
  <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2012</div>
  <div id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2013</div>
  <div id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2014</div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно написать на чистом JS но, не пойму как реализовать
$(this).data();

Comment: `el.getAttribute('data-block-id');`

Comment: var block_id = document.getElementById('block-id');

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich хорошо, а не подскажите как лучше вызывать эту функцию :  стоит ли впихивать в инпут онклик ?

Comment: @CTACO23, обработчики на элементах верхнего уровня всегда предпочтительнее. Не надо каждому инпуту их назначать. Оптимальнее всего, будет назначить единый обработчик элементу `ul`.

Comment: ...но если и вне списка есть элементы которые должны реагировать на клик аналогично, то разумнее слушать событие именно на `document`'е.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation input');
function toggle(){
   var blockId = this.getAttribute('data-block-id'),
    el = document.getElementById(blockId),
    rect = document.querySelectorAll('.rect');
    for(var i = 0; i<rect.length; i++){
      rect[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
}
for(var i = 0; i<input.length; i++){
  input[i].addEventListener('click', toggle)
}
```

```css
.rect{
  visibility:hidden;
  height:100px;
  width:calc(100% / 3);
  float:left;
  background-color:#cda;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <input type="button" data-block-id="b" value="первый">
  <input type="button" data-block-id="bla-bla" value="второй">
  <input type="button" data-block-id="bla" value="третий">
</div>

<div class="rect" id="b"></div>
<div class="rect" id="bla-bla"></div>
<div class="rect" id="bla"></div>
```

Comment: то что нужно!) А как сделать чтоб при нажатии следующего предыдущие убирались ?

Comment: @CTACO23 , внёс правки

Comment: окей, спасибо, но : если блоки расположены в одном месте , то на предыдущий блок переключиться невозможно

Comment: @CTACO23, разве? Видимый блок же по id выбирается. Положение на странице при этом не важно.

Comment: я бы кстати посоветовал обратить внимание на решение от @yar85 . У него js-код компактнее и чище получился.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var block_id = e.target.dataset.blockId; 
  if (block_id && (block_el = document.getElementById(block_id))) {
    alert("gello");
    // [ +] наверное, нужно сначала скрыть ранее показанный(-ые)? 
    for (let b of document.querySelectorAll('#charts > [id^="chart_div"]')) 
      b.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
    // [/+]
    block_el.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n1"><input type="button" value="2010" data-block-id="chart_div"></li>
  <li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" data-block-id="chart_div1"></li>
  <li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" data-block-id="chart_div2"></li>
  <li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" data-block-id="chart_div3"></li>
  <li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" data-block-id="chart_div4"></li>
</ul>

<div id="charts">
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2010</div>
  <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2011</div>
  <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2012</div>
  <div id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2013</div>
  <div id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2014</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation input');
var click = function(event) {
  var block_id = this.getAttribute('data-block-id');
  alert("gello");
  document.getElementById(block_id).style.visibility = 'visible';
};

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
  <li class="n1"><input type="button" value="2010" data-block-id="chart_div"></li>
  <li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" data-block-id="chart_div1"></li>
  <li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" data-block-id="chart_div2"></li>
  <li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" data-block-id="chart_div3"></li>
  <li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" data-block-id="chart_div4"></li>
</ul>

<div id="charts">
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2010</div>
  <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2011</div>
  <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2012</div>
  <div id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2013</div>
  <div id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;visibility:hidden; position:absolute">2014</div>
</div>
```